# Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'IntPtr' == IntPtr ptr1 = [...] --> ptr1[0]

Tags: c#, indexing, intptr

I found a code snippet which I want to implement. Now is the problem that one function isn't running. Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'IntPtr'

```
        fixed (byte* numRef = this.tribuf)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                item = this.trihash.GetItem(ch + S.Substring(i, 3));
                if (item != null)
                {
                    this.TrigramChecked += item.Count;
                    foreach (int num3 in item)
                    {
                        if ((num3 != id) && (numRef[num3] < 0xff))
                        {
                            IntPtr ptr1 = (IntPtr) (numRef + num3);
                            /* ToDo: Error */
                            ptr1[0] = (IntPtr) ((byte) (ptr1[0] + 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

regards Chris

Comment: Do you really need to use this unsafe code at all? Is the performance gain over "normal" code *definitely* worth it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I would try to avoid unsafe code in the first place, but it *looks* like it's really just trying to do:

```
if ((num3 != id) && (numRef[num3] < 0xff))
{
    numRef[num3]++;
}
```

Or perhaps more efficiently (to only read from `numRef[num3]` once):

```
if (num3 != id)
{
    byte value = numRef[num3];
    if (value < 0xff)
    {
        numRef[num3] = (byte) (value + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Konrad: It might, or it might not. I don't know for sure. Hence the "perhaps". It's not *guaranteed* that any changes within the array from other threads would be visible, but equally it's not guaranteed that they won't.

Comment: Could sound a bit blasphemic but shouldn't be the last assignment `= value + 1`? ;-)

Comment: thanks! the first one works fine but the second gives not the same result as the first which is correct.

Comment: @masterchris_99: Gah. Clearly not my day. Hopefully the intention was clear :)